# Building a custom select dropdown Html, Css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a current project and I need to make a custom select drop like the picture I have provided.

So far I was on the idea that I do it like by making an input select, I have made the default select but I need to style it to look like the design and I am having trouble with that

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option>CSS</option>
    <option>HTML </option>
    <option>HTML 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: add your CSS code

Comment: You are fighting browsers on this one, most of the time other libraries do this by replacing the select with an unordered list. See Chosen.js as a good example: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. There's styling you can do but it won't be universally applied in every browser: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/select-css.html

Comment: Corrected typos and code section indentation